# How many 32-bit numbers have five 1's? Combinatorics

Tags: numbers, combinatorics

For each bit (binary digit) that you have, there are two possibilities: Either it can be a zero, or it can be a one.

Therefore, if you have one bit, you have two possible numbers. If you have two bits, each of them can be either a zero or a one, and since there are two possibilities for the first, and two possibilities for the second, there are 2^2=4 total possibilities.

Similarly, if you have some number n of bits, each of them can be a zero or a one, and there will therefore be 2^n possibilities.

I understand this. Because of this fundamental counting principle, I know that there are 2^32 total combinations of 32 bit numbers, but how many have just five 1's?

How do I go about solving this? Count everything that doesn't include five 1's?

Answer (score 1):

You have 32 bits total. Pick 5 to be "1". Order doesn't matter.

```
32C5 = 32!/(5!27!) = 201376
```